# The smallest quadrangle inscribed in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, optimization

I'm supposed to find a quadrangle of the smallest perimeter possible inscribed in a rectangle.
The inscribed quadrangle has each of its four vertices on another side of the rectangle.

Let's call the rectangle ABCD and let the shorter side be $a$ and the larger $b$. Let's call the quadrangle $KLMN$.

So for example $K$ lies on $AB$, $L$ on $BC$, $M$ on $CD$, $N$ on $AD$.

I think that the sides of $KLMN$ would be the shortest of its diagonals intersected at the right angle, because then by the law of cosines, we have $KL^2 + LM^2= KM^2 + 2 KL \cdot LM \cdot \cos  \angle KLM$, and $\cos  \angle KLM \le 0$ if $\angle KLM \ge 90 ^{\circ}$ and $KM$ is the shortest if it is parallel = equal to the proper side of the rectangle.

Could you tell me if I'm right or correct me if I'm wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: There's no such thing, since you could make it arbitrarily small, with perimeter tending to $0$.

Comment: Are you, for example, looking for a vertex on each side of the rectangle? Or every vertex on the perimeter of the rectangle?

Comment: The inscribed quadrangle has $4$ vertices on $4$ sides of the rectangle. I'll add it to my question. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unflod your rectangle to make a grid and place K, L, M and N on it. You goal is to shorten the distance $KL+LM+MN+NK'$.

You need to align $KLMNK'$ to reach the minimal distance for $KK'$. That's $2.AC$

Here is a picture of a non-optimal situation. If it were optimal, then $KLM'N'K'$ would be a straight line.

[image: Illustration]

Here is a picure of an optimal situation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain what you mean by unfolding a rectangle?

Comment: Does it mean "disconnecting" it at a vertex?

Comment: I can't tell if "unfold" is the proper term, here is what I mean:

An a plan: draw $ABCD$, then by symmetry, around $BC$, draw $BCD'A'$, an so one in every direction for every rectangle. It will make a grid.

KL+LM is the same if you place M on $CD'$, etc.

Comment: @Bilou06: I hope you don't mind my editing your post to add an illustration. And I hope I correctly depicted what you had in mind, at least in principle. I believe that there might be a slight difference in where to put these primes, but I couldn't come up with a way that matches your post and seemed consistent to me. And it really doesn't matter that much, it's all the same orbit in any case. Nice answer, by the way!

Comment: @MvG. No problem, i was preparing my own illustration. You contribution perfectly illustrates what my word couldn't expess

Answer (score 2):

I will prove the following: Let $ABCD$ a rectangle having $|AB|=a$ and $|BC|=c$ and let $K$, $L$, $M$, $N$ be points on $AB$, $BC$, $CD$ and $DA$, respectively. Then the perimeter of $KLMN$ is at least $2 \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. This is achievable by letting $K$, $L$, $M$ and $N$ the midpoints of the sides of $ABCD$.

Write $k = |KB|$, $l = |LC|$, $m = |MD|$, $n = |NA|$. Then the perimeter of $KLMN$ equals $\sqrt{k^2+(b-l)^2} + \sqrt{l^2 + (a-m)^2} + \sqrt{m^2+(b-n)^2} + \sqrt{n^2+(a-k)^2}$.

We use Minkowski's inequality
$$\left({\sum_{k \mathop = 1}^n \left({a_k + b_k + c_k + d_k}\right)^p}\right)^{1/p} \le \left({\sum_{k \mathop = 1}^n a_k^p}\right)^{1/p} + \left({\sum_{k \mathop = 1}^n b_k^p}\right)^{1/p} + \left({\sum_{k \mathop = 1}^n c_k^p}\right)^{1/p} + \left({\sum_{k \mathop = 1}^n d_k^p}\right)^{1/p}$$ for $p=n=2$ and sequences $(k,b-l)$, $(a-m,l)$, $(m,b-n)$ and $(a-k,n)$.

We then find 
$$\sqrt{k^2+(b-l)^2} + \sqrt{l^2 + (a-m)^2} + \sqrt{m^2+(b-n)^2} + \sqrt{n^2+(a-k)^2} \geq \sqrt{(k+(a-m)+m+(a-k))^2+((b-l)+l+(b-n)+n)^2} = 2 \sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$ The proof is complete.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you a lot!